# Regex, get entire string between two keywords

Tags: c++, regex

I'm doing some output parsing where I need to grab a chunk of text from inbetween two words. For instance if I'm parsing the text

```
"Hi this is an example"
```

I want to be able to specify that my two words are "Hi" and "example", and i will get back the string

```
" this is an "
```

I know that regular expressions are useful but I'm unfamiliar with them. Any ideas?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I'd recommend learning about the basic regex syntax using a tutorial like [regular expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and playing around with a regex tester like [regex pal](http://regexpal.com/). Just remember, regular expression syntax will differ from language/utility to another, so even if an expression is valid in one place (IE regexpal) it's not always directly translatable to the next.

Comment: c++, sorry I should have mentioned that

Answer (score 3):

You're going to want a regex that looks like

```
Hi(.*?)example
```

We want to capture everything in `()`s

`.` matches any character

`*` means we want from 0 to infinity `.`

We add a `?` at the end so that we match non-greedily otherwise it would gobble up everything until the last "example" in your text, rather that the first "example" after "Hi".

**EDIT:** As far as regex testers go, I like [Rubular](http://rubular.com/). It's techincally ruby specific but works fine for simple things. It shows whole regex matches and the capture groups. Here's your example: http://rubular.com/r/c9I4cmJqBx

Answer (score 3):

This regex will match everything between the two words:

```
(?<=Hi).*(?=example)
```

This regex employs "look arounds" which obviates the need for capturing a group and then extractingg it - the *entire* match is your target.

Comment: -1* for useless lookarounds when a capturing group is best fit for the job. Not only that it's unnecessary complexity and less efficient, getting used to using lookarounds like this can cause problems. For example if you apply the same technique to finding quoted content in `"foo" bar "baz"` you'll get three matches instead of two. *) not really, just saying.

Comment: @Qtax you presume much. You don't know if the OP *requires* the entire match to be the target string. He may want to replace it, or he may need to pass the regex into a method that expects the regex to match the whole target, etc. I prefer avoiding groups because they aren't as clean or versatile as a groupless regex. So there `<pokes-tongue-out/>`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regular expression for this task. Find the index of both words and return what's between the two indexes. You'll have to add the length of the first word to the first index.

```
var search = 'this is a quick test', first = 'this', second = 'test';
search.substring( search.indexOf(first) +  first.length, search.indexOf(second));
```