# regular expression for searching between two words that are the same

Tags: regex

Given the text:

```
PAGE 1
apple

PAGE 2
apple
banana

PAGE 3
orange

PAGE 4
banana

PAGE 5
pear

PAGE 6
apple
orange
banana
pea
```

I want a regular expression that will show me every page a banana is on, which is PAGE 2 and 4.

Things I've tried:

```
PAGE.*?banana.*?PAGE
```

But that returns PAGE 1 and 4.

```
PAGE(?!.*?PAGE).*?banana
```

This was an attempt to look ahead and make sure no extra pages were between the page and the banana words, but this returned nothing.

```
(?<=PAGE).*(?=banana)
```

Borrowed from [Regex, get entire string between two keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993795/regex-get-entire-string-between-two-keywords).  This is returning PAGE 1, matching everything between the last banana and the first PAGE.

I think a look around is the answer, but I can't wrap my head around how to match PAGE # to banana but only the PAGE # the banana is on.  How do I do that?

Comment: You need need to number or the whole block?

Comment: You just need a tempered greedy token solution: [`PAGE \d+\n((?:(?!\bbanana\b|\nPAGE \d+\n).)*\bbanana\b(?:(?!\bbanana\b|\nPAGE \d+\n).)*)(?=\nPAGE \d+\n|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/gE1oN3/1).

Comment: I just need the number.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  That didn't match for me.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I'm reading about tempered greedy now though, I think you may be on to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex.

**Regex:** `PAGE (\d+)\s[^ ]*(?=banana)[^ ]*\n`

**Flags to use:**

- `g` for global search.
- `s` to allow `.` search newline.

**Capture the first group using `\1` or `$1`.**

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hI6jQ7/1)**</kbd>

Comment: I hope your format of data stays same otherwise only **one space to ruin it all**. :D

Comment: @Mike: Is there something missing in this solution ?

Comment: Nope, this works perfectly for the format I supplied.  I posted another that worked for me as well.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Great use for `re.finditer`:

```
txt="""\
PAGE 1
apple

PAGE 2
apple
banana

PAGE 3
orange

PAGE 4
banana

PAGE 5
pear"""

import re

tgt='banana'

for m in re.finditer(r'^PAGE\s+(\d+)\s+([\s\S]+?)(?=^PAGE|\Z)', txt, re.M):
    if re.search(r'(?i){}'.format(tgt), m.group(2)):
        print '"{}" found on Page {}'.format(tgt, m.group(1))
```

Prints:

```
"banana" found on Page 2
"banana" found on Page 4
```

Same technique can produce a mapping of each fruit on which page:

```
di={}
for m in re.finditer(r'^PAGE\s+(\d+)\s+([\s\S]+?)(?=^PAGE|\Z)', txt, re.M):
    for fruit in m.group(2).split():
        di.setdefault(fruit, []).append(m.group(1))
>>> di
{'orange': ['3'], 'pear': ['5'], 'apple': ['1', '2'], 'banana': ['2', '4']}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern

```
(?<=PAGE )(\d+)(?=(?:[^P]|\bP(?!AGE\b))*\bbanana\b)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/352)

Answer (score 0):

Just to give another alternative, this would work as well:

```
^PAGE\s+(?P<page>\d+)[\n\r] # match PAGE + whitespace + digit at the beginning of a line
(?s:                        # open a non-capturing, single-line parenthesis
    (?:.(?!^$))*?           # make not to match an empty line (lazily)
    \bbanana\b              # look for banana with word boundaries
    (?:.(?!^$))*?
)
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hI6jQ7/2).

Answer (score -1):

This worked:

PAGE(?:(?!PAGE).)*?banana

Thanks to Wiktor's comment about using a tempered greedy token solution, I googled and found this page:  http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed

Thanks all!